# javascript exception in while controller in jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I have been trying the javascript in jmeter while controller, and am using below function

```
${__javaScript(("${app_status_g1}".indexOf("100") == -1 && ${App_status_counter} < 10),)}
```

*app_status_g1* is extracted from the regex extractor inside the while controller

However, I get the exception jmeter logs:

```
JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: [("${app_status_g1}".indexOf("100") == -1 && ${App_status_counter} < 10)]
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:45 Expected ) but found {
("${app_status_g1}".indexOf("100") == -1 && ${App_status_counter} < 10)
                                             ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 45
```

Tried few combinations with parentheses but not able to get the cause of problem. But looks like while controller still works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind that JMeter users are strongly recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) with [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language and/or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) for any form of scripting as JavaScript interpreter performance might become the bottleneck and ruin your test.

So consider switching to `__groovy()` function, the equivalent syntax would be:

```
${__groovy((!vars.get('app_status_g1').contains('100') && ((vars.get('App_status_counter') as int) < 10)),)}
```

Comment: thanks, groovy one does not throw parsing exception, but throws NullPointerException as value is not yet initialized: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method contains() on null object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type cast  `${App_status_counter}` to int from String , Because `${App_status_counter}` is a String type variable and you cannot compare it directly.

use `parseInt(${App_status_counter})<10`

So the condition in while loop could be

```
${__javaScript(("${app_status_g1}".indexOf("100") == -1 && parseInt(${App_status_counter}) < 10),)}
```

For more information on while loop please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/jmeter-while-controller/)

and here is the link [working with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609441/jmeter-while-loop/50612008#50612008) in while loop

Please let me know if it helps

Comment: parseInt has similar issue:Error processing Javascript: [("${app_status_g1}".indexOf("100") == -1 && parseInt(${App_status_counter}) < 10)]

javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:54 Expected , but found {
("${app_status_g1}".indexOf("100") == -1 && parseInt(${App_status_counter}) < 10)
                                                      ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 54

Comment: what is the value of App_status_counter?

Comment: Found a similar post @ blazemeter - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter. Pls scroll to the end and see the last but one comment.

Comment: it’s a counter reference variable starting with 1